# Hydrogen - batch export drum loops in different tempos

Tags: software, hydrogen

I use to export `drum loops` from [Hydrogen](http://hydrogen-music.org/) in different tempos. The workflow is quite annoying, because I have to change the `tempo` for each file, go to export and then export the pattern/song to a different audio file.

Does anyone on here know if there is a way to batch export audio from hydrogen, preferably from the `command-line`?